# How to start and stop Wildfly Application server via Java?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-6, wildfly-23

I am working on an application that runs on wildfly. I am trying to start the server from one new Java client as I want to check its status if it started without any errors and based on that want to run an application on the server.

What I tried?
I tried to start it from batch file and tried to run jboss cli command to check if there are boot errors but I am not able to parse the output of the command. Hence I choose to write a java code and tried to use bootable Jar to accomplish this but I am not successful.
Can someone please help me out/guide me to start it fully?

I am expecting the server to start fully and be able to stop it too

Answer (score 0):

Just launch the startup script using Java using the standard methods provided.

I would not recommend running a entire JVM just to launch the server. There are much better ways do check the status of the server than what you are talking about here

Comment: By using process builder?
If I launch it that way, how do we check if the server is fully up without any errors?
Also I should run a file that is deployed on to the server 
Could you please help me with some example?

Comment: There is a launcher-api in WildFly. The Maven GA is `org.wildfly.core:wildfly-launcher`. There is a `StandaoneCommandBuilder` which creates the process for your.